# Vim - Перенос кода между двумя окнами

Tags: vim

Делаю *:vsplit* в **vim**, хотелось бы, чтобы второе содержало продолжение буфера с последней отображаемой строки в первом окне - как две страницы открытой книги. Можно ли такое сделать, и как?

Comment: И в чём сложности? Наберите после сплита - z+

Answer (score 3):

В коммандной строке:

```
:exe 'right vsplit'|exe 'normal z+'
```

Лучше замапить клавишу:

```
:map <F12> :right vsplit<CR>z+
```

Т.к. в книге страницы нумеруются слева на право и читаем мы сверху вниз, а Vim создаёт новые окна поумолчанию слева и вверху, рекомендую это поправить в `vimrc`:

```
set splitbelow
set splitright
```

Тогда нет необходимости `right` перед `vsplit`.

Comment: так окна же не будут синхронизированы. я понял вопрос так, что автор хочет и синхронно листать оба окна. так, чтоб второе было на страницу впереди/позади первого.

Comment: Хмм, я понял, что нет, не надо сихронизировать. Смотря какова цель у автора. Если  досмотреть длинную-предлинную функцию, то раз открыть, полистать в новом окне и закрыть.

Answer (score 2):

можно синхронизировать листание в нескольких окнах с помощью команды `:set scb` (`scb` — это сокращённо, полностью — `scrollbind`).

выполнить её нужно в каждом синхронизируемом окне (чтобы отключить окно от синхронизации, добавьте `no` — `:set noscb`).

можно выполнить сразу во всех открытых окнах командой `:windo set scb`

---

для реализации задуманного вами надо после разбиения на два окна пролистать одно из них на одну страницу. например, нажав `z+` в нормальном режиме, а затем включить синхронизацию окон командой `:windo set scb`

при желании можете эти действия свести в макрос и добавить его в `~/.vimrc`.